# Horizontal flatlist issue

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a view with 2 flatlist, one vertical is working perfectly while the horizontal one doesn't, I can see one card only and it won't move. I searched through the known issues and most of the times is a missing flex-1 but not here.
Any idea? Some Tailwind CSS in it, if it needs clarification please tell me. Thanks

```
const Home = () => {
 
  const renderItem = useCallback(
    ({ item, onpress }) => <VideoListItem onpress={onpress} item={item} />,
    []
  );


 return (
    <>
      <SafeAreaView className="flex-1">
         <KeyboardAvoidingView
          behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "height" : undefined}
          keyboardVerticalOffset={100}
        >
          <View
            className="flex flex-row mx-6 my-2 px-3 py-3 justify-between items-center  "
            style={styles.searchContainer}
          >
            <Image
              className="rounded-full"
              style={{ width: scale(30), height: scale(30) }}
              source={require("../assets/mlucas.jpg")}
            />
            <Ionicons
              name="search-outline"
              size={scale(25)}
              color="px-2 bg-black border"
            />
          </View>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>

        <Text className="text-xl px-6 my-3"> Dernières vidéos</Text>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }} className="px-6 mb-3">
          {data && (
            <>
              <FlatList
                horizontal={true}
                data={data}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.title}
              />
            </>
          )}
        </View>
        <Text className="text-xl px-6 my-3"> Toutes nos vidéos</Text>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }} className="px-6">
          {data && (
            <FlatList
              showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
              data={data}
              renderItem={renderItem}
              keyExtractor={(item) => item.title}
            />
          )}
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
```

and simplified VideoItems

```
const VideoListItem = ({ item, onpress }) => {

  return (
    <Pressable className=' bg-gray-200 border my-2 rounded-2xl' onPress={openVideoPage} style={styles.videoCard}>
    
    <View >
      <Image style={styles.thumbnail} className="rounded-t-2xl" source={{ uri: item.url_image  || "" }} />
          </View>

        <View style={styles.titleRow}>
     
      <View style={styles.midleContainer}>
        <Text className='text-black'style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.subtitle}>
          {item.User?.name || "No name"}
        </Text> 
      </View>

      
    </View>
  </Pressable>
  )
}
```